# Segfault when accessing large memory buffer from ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I get 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' error when accessing memory in Python, which was originally allocated in a shared library.

The function which returns memory is declared as:

```
    extern "C" double *get_sound_data(int desc);
    extern "C" long long get_sound_data_size(int desc);
```

The Python code is:

```
from ctypes import *
cdll.LoadLibrary("libsomelib.so")
_lib = CDLL("libsomelib.so")

size = _lib.get_sound_data_size(desc)
data = _lib.get_sound_data(desc)
data = cast(data, POINTER(c_double))
arr = []
for i in range(size):
    arr.append(data[i])
```

For small buffers, like 10k items it works, but when the library returns a couple of Megabytes the first access attempt, i.e. data[0] in Python segfaults.

I've seen this page and it looks similar https://bugs.python.org/issue13096

I get the same error in Python 2.7.12 and 3.5.2, the OS is Linux.

Comment: You can't just cast a C int to a pointer and assume that's going to work out fine. You need to actually set the right argument and return types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just pretend the default return type is fine and try to cast the nonsense result you get into the type it should have been. (Really, Python probably shouldn't have ever had a default for that, but it's too late to change it.) The default is that C functions are assumed to return C int, and there's no guarantee C int is the same size as a pointer; these days, it's probably not.

You need to actually set `argtypes` and `restype` to be able to use your functions safely through `ctypes`.

```
get_sound_data = _lib.get_sound_data
get_sound_data_size = _lib.get_sound_data_size

get_sound_data.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int,)
get_sound_data.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)

get_sound_data_size.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int,)
get_sound_data_size.restype = ctypes.c_longlong

# Now use the functions
```

Comment: Thank you it works! And what is the correct value for argtypes if the function has f(void) signature?

Comment: @Bord81: `()`, I believe.

Comment: I get 'NameError: name 'function' is not defined'

Comment: I made it as _lib.function() without restype and argtypes and it works.

Comment: @Bord81 `ctypes` assumes `c_int` (generally, 32-bit) for all arguments and return values unless otherwise specified.  Best to be specific.